# updating target workbook extracting data from source workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks One having List of documents with some columns say List

List  city   manager

abc 
abc1 
xyz

and other having names in the list in a column
say A1 having abc

& values of city & manager in other colums say C10 & C11 respectively 
for every item in list I have saperate workbook

I want to add a button so that as I update city & manager in workbook in abc & press the button it get copied into List in row of abc in the List.